# How to store unread messages count for group chat in Laravel app

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, chat

I have read all the answers but still i did not get the answer which i am looking for. Here let me explain what i have and i have done so far.

I have created a chat application where user can have duo chat or a group chat. i have following database structure:

**`chatrooms`**

```
id | creator_id (who created chatroom)  | type (duo/group) |  group_id (if chatroom type is 'group')
```

**`messages`**

```
id  |  chatroom_id  |  senders_id  |  recipient_id  | message  |  read(by default 0)
```

I have one more table to keep track of chatroom participants

**`chatroom_user`**

```
id  | chatroom_id   | user_id
```

Now everything is working fine for duo type chats. 
I am getting unread messages count for duo chat by running this query :

```
return auth()->user()
            ->chatrooms()
            ->withCount(['messages' => function (Builder $query) {
                $query->where('read', 0)->where('recipient_id', auth()->user()->id);
            }])
            ->get();
```

And this works perfectly fine:)

But now if i have group chat i have multiple recipients. i am not able to do what i have done above. So i created one more pivot table

**`message_recipient`**

```
id | message_id  |  recipient_id  | read
```

Now this way i can keep track of unread messages for specific user. But the problem is when i save a message i need to add here so many rows how many recipients are and that for each message. 
suppose i have a group with 10 people if somebody send message 'hello' i need to put 10 records in this table ( actually 10-1 ). 
So my question is: will it be a performance issue? 
Is there any better way to handle this kind of situation ?